# PHP цикл с возвращением ссылки по времени

Tags: php, html, время

```
     <span class="td_download_btn_wrap">
     <?php
     $url0 = "https://google.com/"; 
     $url1 = "https://amazon.com/";

     $t=time("H");
     if ($t= "21") {echo <a href="'.$url0.'" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Te for <b>Windows</b>></a>;}
     if ($t= "22") {echo <a href="'.$url1.'" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Te for <b>Windows</b>></a>;}                                   
      ?>
     </span>
```

Нужно что бы раз в 1 час на сайте заменялась ссылка на другую. Цикл который я написал почему то не работает и на сайт выводит часть кода.
Пожалуйста помогите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй $t = strtotime(date("H:i"));

Comment: Тоже не заработало, возможно не в этом проблема

Comment: Видимо вы не установили и настроили веб-сервер, который будет обрабатывать серверный (PHP) код.

Comment: нет с сервером все ок

Answer (score 2):

```
<span class="td_download_btn_wrap">
<?php
    $url0 = "https://google.com/"; 
    $url1 = "https://amazon.com/";

    $t=time("H");
     
    if ($t == "21") {
        echo '<a href="'.$url0.'" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Te for <b>Windows</b>></a>';
    }
    
    if ($t == "22") {
        echo '<a href="'.$url1.'" class="td_download_btn"><i class="download_icon"></i> Get Te for <b>Windows</b>></a>';
    }                                   
?>
</span>
```

Comment: не помогло, ничего не изменилось

Comment: `==` там должно быть а не `=`

Comment: Изменил но цикл все равно не запустился

Comment: Где здесь цикл?